# Azure Stream Analytics Window based on variable time

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics

I know I can create Stream Analytics windows as follows:

```
TumblingWindow(second, 30)
```

This would make fixed windows every 30 seconds.

Is it possible to make the 30 seconds dynamic? This would mean we get multiple windows through each other, all on different time schedules.

I'm experimenting with reference input file's, and I would like to get the amount of seconds from the reference file, rather than fixed in the query.

If I create the Window with input from a reference file, I get the error:

> Error : Invalid window duration: 'timespanInSeconds'. Window duration must be a positive float constant.

Even though it seems to be a valid json number. Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something in the docs that I've found:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/reference/tumbling-window-azure-stream-analytics

It states:

> A big integer which describes the size of the window. The windowsize is static and cannot be changed dynamically at runtime.

Comment: There is a reason why window size is a constant. If it is taken from reference data (or event stream itself) then what would be the semantics of unclosed windows at the time the window size changes due to the new size in reference data? Will these windows close immediately, will the new size only take effect after current window/s close, or any other possible option? It is also likely that there exists a different approach to what you trying to achieve, without the need to dynamically change the window size. Maybe consider session window?

Comment: Yeap! My plan is to notify a function, which can keep state in the database. For certain data I need to do something after one minute, for another after 5, and for another after 15, etc.. So it seems normal Windowing (also session windowing) won't suit my case. Thanks for the clarification.